When using the aws cli to send a SQS message how do I get it to accept JSON?
I'm using elasticmq docker image to setup a local testing queue.
I setup the queue fine using
aws --region=us-west-2 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs create-queue --queue-name=jobs

But when I try to send a message I get just get an error
aws --region=us-west-2 --endpoint=http://localhost:9324 sqs send-message --queue-url http://localhost:9324/000000000000/jobs --message-body {"FileHashes": ["79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4"] }

error is zsh: parse error near '}'

I would bet this format will work "{"FileHashes":["79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4"]}"

Yup that was it, I was just escaping incorrectly when I tried.

A minimal reproducible example would be echo {x }, which produces the same parse error.

I was escaping incorrectly,
Using "{\"FileHashes\":[\"79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4\"]}" works.

Braces are used in zsh to express a compound statement:
{ echo a; echo b }

prints
a
b

Another use of braces is in the context of brace expansion:
echo {a,b}

prints
a b

In brace expansion, there must be no wordsplitting between the braces. Hence,
echo {a, b}
echo {a,b }

would both be wrong.
A special case is a single word delimited by braces, which does not have a comma in it:
echo {ab}

prints
{ab}

In your case, you have a lone }, which looks to zsh as the end of a compound, but the corresponding { is missing.
Since you want neither a compound block, nor brace expansion, the simplest way would be to just not use braces as a special character, but to quote the whole stuff:
--message-body '{"FileHashes": ["79054025255fb1a26e4bc422aef54eb4"] }'

